# Aggregate objects using LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have SQL query to get count of blocks, grouping by block name

```
var sql = @"select count(*) [COUNT], o.NAME from WISH w
                            left join objects o on o.ID = w.[BLOCKID]
                            where w.ISDELETE = 0
                            group by o.NAME"
var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
Label labelClear = (Label)Master.FindControl("labelClear");

if (reader.HasRows)
{
   while (reader.Read())
   {
      labelClear.Text += reader["NAME"].ToString() + " - " + reader["COUNT"].ToString() + "; ";
   }
 }
```

which make output string like:

```
"BLOCKNAME1 - 15; BLOCKNAME2 - 3; BLOCKNAME3 - 28" etc.
```

(where 15, 3 and 28 - count of BLOCKNAME1, BLOCKNAME2 and BLOCKNAME3).

And I try to convert this query to LINQ:

```
((Label)Master.FindControl("labelClear")).Text = 
Db.WISH.Where(x => x.ISDELETE == 0)
.GroupBy(x => x.OBJECTS_BLOCK.NAME)
.Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Cnt =  SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal?)g.Count()) })
.Aggregate((a, b) => a.Name + ": " + a.Cnt + ", " + b.Name + ": " + b.Cnt );
```

But get error on last line (with Aggregate):

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'AnonymousType#2'
```

What is correct way to aggregate result into string like

```
"BLOCKNAME1 - 15; BLOCKNAME2 - 3; BLOCKNAME3 - 28"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try that one:

```
((Label)Master.FindControl("labelClear")).Text = 
Db.WISH.Where(x => x.ISDELETE == 0)
.GroupBy(x => x.OBJECTS_BLOCK.NAME)
.Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Cnt =  SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal?)g.Count()) })
.AsEnumerable()
.Aggregate(string.Empty, (a, b) => a + ", " + b.Name + ": " + b.Cnt, s => s.Substring(2));
```

Explanation for `Aggregate` parameters:

- `string.Empty` - initial seed value
- `(a, b) => a + ", " + b.Name + ":" + b.Cnt` - aggregation function. It concatenates current seed value with new value string.
- `s => s.Substring(2)` - result selection function. Removes first 2 characters, which are unnecessary `,`

`AsEnumerable` is necessary to move string concatenation from DB into application. EF does not support `Aggregate` method with that parameters. `Count()` is still performed by DB.

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you! But could you explain please, how it works (what means string.Empty at the begin, why 'a' without '.Name' and '.Cnt' and for what reason 's => s.Substring(2)')

Comment: If I understand correctly, adding seed value 'string.Empty' allow cast type {Name, Cnt} to string?

Comment: No, it allows your aggregation result to be a string.

Comment: Using String.Empty as the seed, it's so obvious! Why didn't I think of that? Thank-you thank-you thank-you!!